# Lost boot from the hard drive after installing kali linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot

I have tried to install Kali-linux with Windows 8.1. So I disabled fast and secure boot and  installed the Kali normally but when I restarted my PC after the installation, it tell me:

**"Reboot and Select proper Boot device"**

I checked the order:

1-HDD 
2-USB 
3-CD/DVD

Now I'm working just from live USB so please tell me how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140424002809-79939846-windows-8-1-and-kali-linux-dual-boot-on-uefi-mode-machines):

> By default, Kali Linux is not UEFI enabled.

Which may explain why it's not booting now. Basically you need an UEFI enabled grub. Try going through the steps in the article, looks like he was in the same situation.

Comment: i followed all the steps in that article but nothing. i lost now the boot for windows8.1 is there any way to repair it ( i don't have a recovery disk) ??

Comment: Not sure about repair, but put [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) boot manager on a CD or USB stick, that should at least allow you to boot...